# For loop question in R

Tags: r, file, for-loop

Hope I can explain my question well enough to obtain an answer - any help will be appreciated.

I have a number if data files which I need to merge into one. I use a for loop to do this and add a column which indicates which file it is.

In this case there are 6 files with up to 100 data entries in each.

When there are 6 files I have no problem in getting this to run.

But when there are less I have a problem.

What I would like to do is use the for loop to test for the files and use the for loop variable to assemble a vector which references the files that exist.

I can't seem to get the new variable to combine the new value of the for loop variable as it goes through the loop.

Here is the sample code I have written so far.

```
for ( rloop1 in 1 : 6) {
ReadFile=paste(rloop1,SampleName,"_",FileName,"_Stats.csv", sep="")
if (file.exists(ReadFile))
**files_found <- c(rloop1)**
}
```

What I am looking for is that files_found will contain those files where 1...6 are valid for the files found.

Regards
Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a much shorter way to do this using list.files() as Henrik showed. In case you're not familiar with regular expressions (see `?regex`), you could do.

```
n <- 6
Fnames <- paste(1:n,SampleName,"_",FileName,"Stats.csv",sep="")
Filelist <- Fnames[file.exists(Fnames)]
```

which is perfectly equivalent. Both `paste` and `file.exists` are vectorized functions, so you better make use of that. There's no need for a for-loop whatsoever.

To get the number of the filenames (assuming that's the only digits), you can do:

```
gsub("^[:digit:]","", Filelist)
```

See also `?regex`

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the vectorized version of `file.exists` is much prettier than the for-loop. But, from my point, `list.files()` is even nicer as you have it all in one line... (nevertheless +1)

Comment: Yes SampleName and FileName are strings. One small point, I would have liked to have obtained the number associated with each file found since I need to add a column to the file with that number for all the records in that file. Any ideas?

Comment: @Steve I added it in my answer.

Comment: @Joris - Thanks. Have tried your gsub and I think corrected digits to digit (is that a typo error) but either way only get all the applicable files in Filelist. Have looked through regxex info but found it quite confusing. If you have time to take a look and guide me that would be great. To clarify if string was "3A_SampleName_FileName_stats.csv" I would get a 3 and if it was "2A....." I would get a 2 etc

Comment: @Steve: nice catch, sorry for the typo. try `gsub("^(.+?)_.+","\\1",Filelist)`, presuming you have 3A_SampleName_... as filename and read ?regex again carefully. It's not easy material, but it's very powerful once you get the hang of it. Just try to work out different examples. On a sidenote, you might want to consider one of the answers to accept as the correct one (use the V symbol on the left). See also the FAQ

Comment: @Joris: Thanks once again. I'll give it a bash and see if I can get it to work. Liked your answer since there is no for..next loop. Just got to get my head around vectorised functions and regex.

Answer (score 7):

It would probably be better to list the files you want to load, and then loop over that list to load them. `list.files` is your friend here. We can use a regular expression to list only those files that end in `"_Stats.csv"`. For example, in my current working directory I have the following files:

```
$ ls | grep Stats
bar_Stats.csv
foobar_Stats.csv
foobar_Stats.csv.txt
foo_Stats.csv
```

Only three of them are csv files I want to load (the `.txt` file doesn't match the pattern you showed). We can get these file names using `list.files()`:

```
> list.files(pattern = "_Stats.csv$")
[1] "bar_Stats.csv"    "foo_Stats.csv"    "foobar_Stats.csv"
```

You can then loop over that and read the files in. Something like:

```
fnames <- list.files(pattern = "_Stats.csv$")
for(i in seq_along(fnames)) {
    assign(paste("file_", i, sep = ""), read.csv(fnames[i]))
}
```

That will create a series of objects `file_1`, `file_2`, `file_3` etc in the global workspace. If you want the files in a list, you could instead `lapply` over the `fnames`:

```
lapply(fnames, read.csv)
```

and if suitable, `do.call` might help combine the files from the list:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(fnames, read.csv))
```

Comment: list.files + grep + lapply + do.call is a winning combination in my book.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are better solutions (e.g., you could use `list.files()` to scan the folder and then loop over the length of the returned object), but this should (I didn't try it) do the trick (using your sample code):

```
files.found <- ""    
for (rloop1 in 1 : 6) {
    ReadFile=paste(rloop1,SampleName,"_",FileName,"_Stats.csv", sep="")
    if (file.exists(ReadFile)) files_found <- c(files.found, rloop1)
}
```

Alternatively, you could get the fileNames (other than their index) via:

```
files.found <- ""    
for (rloop1 in 1 : 6) {
    ReadFile=paste(rloop1,SampleName,"_",FileName,"_Stats.csv", sep="")
    if (file.exists(ReadFile)) files_found <- c(files.found, ReadFile)
}
```

Finally, in your case `list.files` could look something like this:

```
files.found <- list.files(pattern = "[[:digit:]]_SampleName_FileName_Stats.csv")
```

Comment: +1 for the `list.files()` pointer and the regexp. In the regexp, `SampleName` and `FileName` were not literals but strings in R objects, at least that was my reading of the Q.

Comment: @Gavin my reading, too. Perhaps I should clarify that `SampleName` and `FileName` should be replaced by their values and can not be variables.